# Dynamically add metrics to Fabric8 MetricSpecBuilder

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, fabric8

I want to create HPA using the Fabric8 API. I want to dynamically add metrics to the MetricSpecBuider.
Something like the following,

```
        HorizontalPodAutoscaler horizontalPodAutoscaler = new HorizontalPodAutoscalerBuilder()
            .withNewMetadata().withName("${config.metadata_name}-hpa").endMetadata()
            .withNewSpec()
            .withNewScaleTargetRef()
            .withApiVersion("apps/v1")
            .withKind("Deployment")
            .withName("${config.metadata_name}")
            .endScaleTargetRef()
            .withMinReplicas(1)
            .withMaxReplicas(10)
            .addToMetrics(new io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.MetricSpecBuilder()
            for (metric in config.deploy_env.metrics) {
                .withType(metric.type)
                .withNewResource()
                .withName(metric.resource.name)
                .withNewTarget()
                .withType(metric.resource.target.type)
                .withAverageUtilization(metric.resource.target.averageUtilization)
                .endTarget()
                .endResource()
            }
            .build())
            .endSpec()
            .build()
        return horizontalPodAutoscaler
```

However, this results in an error.

```
81: unexpected token: for @ line 81, column 4.
11:19:14                for (metric in config.deploy_env.metrics) {
11:19:14        ^
11:19:14  
11:19:14  1 error
11:19:14
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: share the error logs

Comment: 81: unexpected token: for @ line 81, column 4.
11:19:14        for (metric in config.deploy_env.metrics) {
11:19:14        ^
11:19:14  
11:19:14  1 error
11:19:14

Comment: You can easily do it using `addNewMetric()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Fabric8 team. I think you should be able to create a new metric dynamically using `addNewMetric()` method in the builder. I think you need to something like this in order to add new metrics dynamically. You can also create a `List<MetricSpec>` dynamically and assign it to builder with `withMetrics(metricsList)`.

This code is based of Fabric8 Kubernetes Client v4.10.3:

```
HorizontalPodAutoscalerBuilder horizontalPodAutoscalerBuilder = new HorizontalPodAutoscalerBuilder()
        .withNewMetadata().withName("the-hpa").withNamespace("default").endMetadata()
        .withNewSpec()
        .withMetrics()
        .withNewScaleTargetRef()
        .withApiVersion("apps/v1")
        .withKind("Deployment")
        .withName("the-deployment")
        .endScaleTargetRef()
        .withMinReplicas(1)
        .withMaxReplicas(10)
        .withNewBehavior()
        .withNewScaleDown()
        .addNewPolicy()
        .withType("Pods")
        .withValue(4)
        .withPeriodSeconds(60)
        .endPolicy()
        .addNewPolicy()
        .withType("Percent")
        .withValue(10)
        .withPeriodSeconds(60)
        .endPolicy()
        .endScaleDown()
        .endBehavior()
        .endSpec();

for (int i = 0; i < metricInput.length; i++) {
    horizontalPodAutoscalerBuilder
            .editOrNewSpec()
            .addNewMetric()
            .withType(metricInput[i])
            // ...
            .endMetric()
            .endSpec();
}

return horizontalPodAutoscalerBuilder.build()
```